# Plural form composed of three nouns

Tags: nouns, plural-forms

In my work I need to describe "groups of metrics". I'm not sure if I should write "metrics groups" or "metric groups" (I tend to "<s>metrics</s> metric groups" now). And now I'm confused with "names of groups of metrics". "Metrics groups names" sound odd, as do "metrics group names". How should I write this?

Comment: What is the context of your work? "Metrics" and "groups" are both mathematical terms. Do you mean this in the mathematical sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely *must* create a single multi-part noun and make it plural, then the practice is to pluralize only the last noun:

> metric group names
>
> firefighter activist administrator corps
>
> jeans inspector assistant committees

These can sound a little weird, so it's better to either use "of", or change the modifying nouns to adjectives:

> the corps of activist firefighter administrators
>
> the committees of jeans inspection assistants

and so on.